# how can i test my website with ie6

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-6

i worked on a website in the latest firefox and then presented it on a machine that just had ie6 (and it looked horrible).  is there anyway i can test what it will look like in IE6 without having to actually download.  I see that ie8 has a compatibility mode (to show what it would look like in ie7), is there a similar thing for ie 6?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Get Microsoft Virtual PC (it's free).  You can download images with IE6, IE7, and IE8 for all your wtf-microsoft! debugging needs.

http://www.microsoft.com/windows/virtual-pc/

Also, don't trust IE8 compatibility mode.

Comment: Yea, I too have a VPC running XP with IE6 and FF2.

Comment: If you development machine is linux you can use virtualBox on linux which is again a free virtualization software where you can install windows XP with IE6.

Answer (score 7):

Here is the link to the VPC images from MS for testing in many OS and browser combinations

http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=21eabb90-958f-4b64-b5f1-73d0a413c8ef&displaylang=en

Answer (score 3):

You can upload your website to some free hosting provider. Then use http://browsershots.org/ to test your website in almost all the available browsers (incl IE6).

The website will take screen shots of your website.

Answer (score 2):

you can try

http://browsershots.org/

http://crossbrowsertesting.com/

and the one i like most 'https://browserlab.adobe.com/index.html#'

Answer (score 1):

I have a testing PC in which i have IE6 installed. And i check the pages on that. I recommend that this approach is the best as testing on IE6 itself is the best.

Answer (score 1):

I use Microsoft Virtual PC, and IETester. But when I need a quick preview (or am traveling with my MacBook Pro) [Adobe Browser Lab](http://browserlab.adobe.com/) is Awesome! You can't test interactivity, but display bugs you can test very quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Online service:

[Browser Shots](http://browsershots.org/)

Locally on your machine:

[VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/)

Answer (score 1):

[Adobe's BrowserLab](https://browserlab.adobe.com/index.html) is a great service if all you need is a screenshot. However, if you need to test the interaction with the site, [MultipleIE](http://tredosoft.com/Multiple_IE) can install IE6 as well as previous versions (not really necessary, though).

If you're looking for tons of browsers and just screenshot functionality, [BrowserShots](http://browsershots.org/) is another great tool.

Answer (score 1):

Evolt's browser archive has legacy IE installs, including standalone versions:
http://browsers.evolt.org/?ie/

Comment: IE Developer Toolbar is also handy (it's like a buggy, feature-stripped version of Firebug):
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?familyid=95E06CBE-4940-4218-B75D-B8856FCED535&displaylang=en

Answer (score 1):

Web based alternatives: (by providing screenshots)
http://netrenderer.com/index.php