# Is IE 6 skipped in HTTP-EQUIV compatibility modes?

Tags: internet-explorer, compatibility-mode

[This article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc196988%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) specifies IE 9 (Edge), IE8, IE7 and IE5 as valid HTTP-EQUIV document modes. Why was IE6 skipped? Does it render the same as IE5? My company supports IE6+, so I want to find a reliable way to test IE6 compatibility UI changes without requiring a VM.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The article specifies the [compatibility modes](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askie/archive/2009/03/23/understanding-compatibility-modes-in-internet-explorer-8.aspx) IE (8-9) can run in. IE5(.5) equals to [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode). IE8 cannot run in IE6 compatibility mode. IE6 does not absolutely render the same as IE5(.5) (unless it's in quirks mode).

If you want a reliable way to test in IE6, IE7, etc., you should try something like [IETester](http://www.my-debugbar.com/wiki/IETester/HomePage) (which I found to be reliable), [Spoon](http://spoon.net/browsers/), etc. if you don't want to use VMs.

You should also check this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1830651/how-can-i-test-my-website-with-ie6). As stated there:

> Also, don't trust IE8 compatibility
>   mode.

Comment: Spoon no longer supports IE, and I've tried IETester but it often crashes, not to mention according to this SO question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347860/ie-6-or-ie-tester) it doesn't accurately render IE 6 or 7.

Comment: Still much better than compatibility mode. You cannot get better results than with the VPC though :).

Comment: Still, for UI testing, IE Tester seems to be reliable for me.